# Swipe View: как получить View из Activity

Tags: android, view, java, activity

Использую данный код для основы приложения - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

В одном из фрагментов размещаю ListView:

**Код фрагмента:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_objects, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    return rootView;
}
```

**XML (load_objects):**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

При добавлении пункта в ListView из фрагмента - все отлично.
Но вот как не пытался добавить пункт из Activity - всегда возвращало **null**.
Как узнать View через Activity? Пытался и **findViewById** указав **LinearLayout ID**, **findFragmentById** и **findFragmentByTag** тоже вернули **null**. Если вместо View указываю getActivity - приложение вылетает. Что только не перепробывал. Перерыл ХэшКод и StackOverflow - без результатов. Дайте дельный совет. 2 ночь не сплю :(

Comment: getView()?

Comment: ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  на getView() ошибку дает, я пологаю перед getView() должен быть метод фрагмента, но узнать фрагмент я пытался, все также.

Comment: нужно больше когда по моменту    
>Пытался и findViewById указав LinearLayout ID, findFragmentById и findFragmentByTag тоже вернули null.

Comment: fragment.getView()?

Comment: Ну по хорошему вам этого и не надо делать. Управлять View фрагмента должен сам фрагмент.

Comment: определите во фрагменте функцию, которая будет принимать модель элемента списка, и добавлять в адаптер элемент, и вызывайте ее в активити. fragment.addListItem(ListItem item);